# Lambda forgot how to interpret JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, aws-lambda

I've got something really weird happening in Lambda. I have a JS function that is interpreting a string input. This code is covered by unit tests to confirm that the validation logic is working as expected. But once it's deployed to Lambda I get different behavior. Is there a really noob error that I'm overlooking. Or is there some setting in Lambda that might explain why my code is being interpreted differently.

Here is my function:

```
public async processMessage(message: string): Promise<void> {
    logger.info(`Message: ${message}`);
    const params = JSON.parse(message);


    if ('fileId' in params && 'location' in params && 'fileType' in params) {
        return this.fileLoader.load(params.fileId, params.location, fromString(params.fileType));
    } else {
        throw new InvalidArgumentError('A required field on the message is missing.');
    }
}
```

The validation works as expected, the function is invoked correctly. Everything seems great!
Then I deploy it up to lambda and call it there. I get this error:

```
Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'fileId' in {\"fileId\":\"1234\",\"fileType\": \"TEST_FILE\",\"location\": \"https://d4-file-proc-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/testFile.csv\"}
```

Here's the CloudWatch Logs:

```
Message: "{\"fileId\":\"1234\",\"fileType\": \"TEST_FILE\",\"location\": \"https://d4-file-proc-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/testFile.csv\"}"
ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection     
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
    "errorMessage": "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'fileId' in {\"fileId\":\"1234\",\"fileType\": \"TEST_FILE\",\"location\": \"https://d4-file-proc-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/testFile.csv\"}",
    "reason": {
        "errorType": "TypeError",
        "errorMessage": "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'fileId' in {\"fileId\":\"1234\",\"fileType\": \"TEST_FILE\",\"location\": \"https://d4-file-proc-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/testFile.csv\"}",
        "stack": [
            "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'fileId' in {\"fileId\":\"1234\",\"fileType\": \"TEST_FILE\",\"location\": \"https://d4-file-proc-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/testFile.csv\"}",
            "    at FileLoaderMessageHandler.processMessage (/var/task/dist/infrastructure/fileLoaderMessageHandler.js:14:22)",
            "    at /var/task/dist/aws/fileLoader.js:23:57",
            "    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)",
            "    at Runtime.exports.handle [as handler] (/var/task/dist/aws/fileLoader.js:23:18)",
            "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
        ]
    },
    "promise": {},
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'fileId' in {\"fileId\":\"1234\",\"fileType\": \"TEST_FILE\",\"location\": \"https://d4-file-proc-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/testFile.csv\"}",
        "    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)",
        "    at process.emit (events.js:210:5)",
        "    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:476:20)",
        "    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:201:33)",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:32)"
    ]
}
```

I tried refactoring it to use use Object.keys as well. But it's still performing oddly.

```
function isFileLoaderParams(params: any): params is FileLoaderParams {
    logger.info(`INPUT: ${params}`);

    if (!params.fileId) {
        logger.warn('FileId not found');
        logger.info(`DoubleCheck: ${JSON.stringify(params)}`);
        logger.info(`Value Is: ${JSON.stringify(params.fileId)}`);
        logger.info(`ArrayAccess?: ${JSON.stringify(params['fileId'])}`);
        return false;
    }

    if (!params.location) {
        logger.warn('Location not found');
        return false;
    }

    if (!params.fileType) {
        logger.warn('FileType not found');
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Which generates this output:

```
INPUT: {"fileId":"1234","fileType": "TEST_FILE","location": "https://d4-file-proc-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/testFile.csv"}
FileId not found
DoubleCheck: "{\"fileId\":\"1234\",\"fileType\": \"TEST_FILE\",\"location\": \"https://d4-file-proc-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/testFile.csv\"}"
Value Is: undefined
ArrayAccess?: undefined
```

## Configuration/environment details

- Written in typescript
- Complied by tsc using Typescript 8.3.0
- Deployed using Serverless framework
- Lambda Runtime: Node.js 12.x (Also ran it in Node 10, but upgraded to 12 trying to fix this)

Comment: It looks like `params` is a String, you'll have to use `const params = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(message));` or make sure you're sending a valid JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error means that `params` is a `String`, not an object. Perhaps your `message` is a double-encoded JSON string (a JSON string containing a JSON string). I'm not sure how it got there, but look for logic that is doing a `JSON.stringify` on something that's already JSON. Or as @Titus mentioned, doing a double-decode:

```
const params = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(message));
```

Comment: I hadn't even considered double-encoded. Didn't know that was a thing. All I was seeing was "Call `JSON.parse`" but thought I already had that covered.